# Turn button into scroll if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code initially loads more content when the bottom button is clicked but I need it to work when the scroll reach the bottom of the page... I've tried the code under the words //HERE IS THE PROBLEM// but it seems not to work.... any idea?

```js
var lazyload = lazyload || {};

(function($, lazyload) {

    "use strict";

    var page = 2,
        buttonId = "#button-more",
        loadingId = "#loading-div",
        container = "#container";
  
  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
     
    lazyload.load = function() {

        var url = "./" + page + ".html";

        $(buttonId).hide();
        $(loadingId).show();

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(response) {
                if (!response || response.trim() == "NONE") {
                    $(buttonId).fadeOut();
                    $(loadingId).text("No more entries to load!");
                    return;
                }
                appendContests(response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                $(loadingId).text("Sorry, there was some error with the request. Please refresh the page.");
            }
        });
    };
}
});
    var appendContests = function(response) {
        var id = $(buttonId);

        $(buttonId).show();
        $(loadingId).hide();

        $(response).appendTo($(container));
        page += 1;
    };

})(jQuery, lazyload);
```

```css
body{
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper{
 width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#data-container{
    margin: 10px;
}

#data-container .data-item{
    background-color: #444444;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 105px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}

#loading-div{
    display: none;
}

#button-more{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.child{
 width:100%;
 height:1000px;
 background-color:blue;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
            <h1>Lazy Load Demo</h1>
            <div id="container">
                <div class="child">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="button-more" onclick="lazyload.load()">
                Load more items
            </div>
            <div id="loading-div">
                loading more items
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to include any of your code.

Comment: where is your code yar?

Comment: Sorry @krillgar I forgot to add it, now is ready.

Comment: hi @GaneshPutta I already added it

Answer (score 0):

```js
let more = document.querySelector("button");
let show = document.querySelector(".show");
let loading = document.querySelector(".loading");
let bottom = document.querySelector(".bottom");
let allowAjax = true;


function getAjax(){
 loading.classList.add("show");

  if(allowAjax === true){
  
  allowAjax = false;
  
  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    let back = xhttp.response;
    back = JSON.parse(back);
    let imgSrc = back.results[0].picture.large;

    let imgEl = document.createElement("img");
    imgEl.src = imgSrc;
    show.appendChild(imgEl);
    loading.classList.remove("show");
    allowAjax = true;

   }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://randomuser.me/api/", true);
  xhttp.send();
  
 }
 
 
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
 
 let scrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
 let bottomPos = bottom.offsetTop;
 
 if(bottomPos / 1.5 <= scrollPos){
  
  // Almost to the bottom of the page
  getAjax();
  
 }
 
});


more.addEventListener("click",function(){
 
 getAjax();

});
```

```css
img{
  
  display: block;
 width: 30em;
 height: 30em;
  
}

.more{
  
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  right: 5em;
  background: skyblue;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.loading{
 width: 10em;
 height: 10em;
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 top: 5em;
 right: 1em;
 background: #212323;
 padding: 0.5em;
}

.loading.show{
 display: block;
}

.show img{
 
 display: block;
 width: 30em;
 height: 30em;
 
}
```

```html
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300/?random" />
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300/?random" />


<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300/?random" />
<img src="https://unsplash.it/300/300/?random" />

<div class="show"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<button class="more">More</button>



<img src="http://www.lettersmarket.com/uploads/lettersmarket/blog/loaders/common_metal/ajax_loader_metal_512.gif"class="loading">
```

initially loads